# Nginx basic_auth

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication

I have settings:

```
location / {auth_basic "Private zone";auth_basic_user_file /user/.httpasswds;}
```

and

```
location index.html {auth_basic off;}
```

`www.myserver.org/index.html` works perfect without basic auth dialog,

Index file is index.html,
but `www.myserver.org` or `www.myserver.org/` asks password.

How to solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to accept connections for `/` and `/index.html` without authentication.

```
index index.html;

location = / { }

location = /index.html { }

location / {
    auth_basic "Private zone";
    auth_basic_user_file /user/.httpasswds;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.